# Delete HipChat messages via the API

Tags: hipchat

Pretty simple -- I've searched a lot online for ways to delete messages in HipChat via the API, but haven't found anything on how to do it. The only thing I did find was [this ticket](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/HipChat-questions/Is-there-a-way-to-delete-a-hipchat-message-via-the-api/qaq-p/7750) on the community forums, but it's a few years old and I'm not sure whether this feature is still unavailable. If it is available, how exactly do you do it and where can I find a reference to this in the documentation?

Comment: They have a [reference documentation page](https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2). There might have what you're looking for. Isn't there?

Comment: @Lucasandreybleme I mean a reference in the documentation that specifically deals with how to delete messages via the API.

Comment: Oh, I see... Take a look at my aswer. Remember marking it as right if it completly answer your question @GDP2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Untill now, it is not possible to delete HipChat messages via API.

[See the issue here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/HipChat-questions/Is-there-a-way-to-delete-a-hipchat-message-via-the-api/qaq-p/7750).

Comment: Yeah, the noted issue is old though and the linked issues to upvote appear to be gone... any links to newer information on this?

Comment: Didn't found. Maybe contact the Atlassian support is the best solution...

Comment: Alright, I'll contact them and accept your answer here if it is still an unavailable feature.